# What will occur if I would use non final ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I read somewhere that even if `ConcurrentHashMap` is guaranteed to be safe for using in multiple threads it should be declared as `final`, even `private final`. My questions are the following:

1) Will `CocurrentHashMap` still keep thread safety without declaring it as `final`?

2) The same question about **private** keyword. Probably it's better to ask more general question - do `public/private` keywords **affect on runtime behavior**? I understand their meaning in terms of visibility/usage in internal/external classes but what about meaning in the context of multithreading runtime? I believe code like `public ConcurrentHashMap` may be incorrect only in *coding style* terms not in runtime, am I right?

Comment: You need to explain more about your use case. The recommendation to make a reference `final` is made in the context of some specific arrangement of threads and objects, and while it's even required by the language in some situations, it's not always the best choice.

Comment: `final` and `private` say *nothing* about the thread-safety (or lack thereof) of the *object* named by said variable. (They modify the *variable*, not the *object*.)

Comment: final => cannot be reassigned, private => cannot be accessible from outside the class. Agree with @user2864740

Comment: @Nishant, so if I I'm not going to reassign my map does it mean I can use non-final declaration and be sure that my map is thread safe?

Comment: @user2864740, thanks for pointing information about out single operations) I'm going to use CHM in primitive way - `put(Integer fileID,Boolean opened)` and `get(Integer fileId)`. No `isEmpty()` or `clear()` operations - do you mean their usage are not thread safe?

Comment: If the map is not `final`, and the object that contains that field is unsafely published (for instance, by writing it to a non-`volatile` static field), then another thread could read a stale value for the reference -- including its original `null` value. That said, if the thread reads the correct reference, then the `ConcurrentHashMap` object itself will be safe. As for public/private, that has no affect on thread safety.

Comment: @Baurzhan Methods like `isEmpty()` and `clear()` are safe. What's not safe is assuming that their results are valid in the next statement or expression! For instance, something like `assert map.isEmpty() ==  (map.size() == 0)` ("iff the map is empty, it has size 0") is not safe, because some code may have cleared the map between `map.isEmpty()` and `map.size()`. Similarly, something like `map.clear(); assert map.isEmpty();` might fail, because another thread could have inserted into the map between the clear and the assert. Only individual method calls are safe without extra synchronization.

Comment: @yshavit, if I understand you properly `final` keyword is insurance for **reading null reference** situations? So, if I gurantee, that CHM instantiated **before** other threads read/modify it `final` keyword is not necessary?

Comment: @Baurzhan Kinda. Specifically, you have to ensure that the field that references the CHM is assigned before other threads read it. Note that assigning the field in the constructor is _not_ enough -- the weirdnesses of multithreading mean that if the object is unsafely published, a thread could see the object but not everything that happened in its constructor! The easiest thing to do is to make the CHM field `final`. There are other, trickier, subtle ways to do it... but they're easy to get wrong, and a `final` field is easy to get right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful to give a more concrete example of what I was talking about in the comments. Let's say I do something like this:

```
public class CHMHolder {

    private /*non-final*/ CHMHolder instance;

    public static CHMHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CHMHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now, this is not thread-safe for a whole bunch of reasons! But let's say that threadA sees a `null` value for `instance` and thus instantiates the `CHMHolder`, and then threadB, by a happy coincidence, sees that same `CHMHolder` instance (which is not guaranteed, since there's no synchronization). You would think that threadB sees a non-`null` `CHMHolder.map`, right? It might not, since there's no formal happens-before edge between threadA's `map = new ...` and threadB's `return map`.

What this means in practice is that something like `CHMHolder.getInstance().getMap().isEmpty()` could throw a `NullPointerException`, which would be confusing — after all, `getInstance` looks like it should always return a non-`null` `CHMHolder`, and `CHMHolder` looks like it should always have a non-`null` map. Ah, the joys of multithreading!

If `map` were marked `final`, then the JLS bit that user2864740 referenced applies. That means that if threadB sees the same instance that threadA sees (which, again, it might not), then it'll also see the `map = new...` action that `threadA` did -- that is, it will see the non-`null` CHM instance. Once it sees that, CHM's internal thread safety will be enough to ensure safe access.

Comment: According to the JMM specifications, a worse scenario than the one you describe may occur; thread B may see a non null map instance, but that instance may be partially constructed, being in an inconsistent state.

Comment: No, because `ConcurrentHashMap`'s underlying state is itself in `final` fields (at least in [openjdk 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)), so any thread that sees the CHM instance must see those fields as they were set at construction time. The only non-`final` fields are the three views (keySet, entrySet, values) which are instantiated as-needed in a carefully constructed benign data race (the instantiation is racey but idempotent).

Comment: I checked Sun's JDK and it seems to have the same benign data race in ConcurrentHashMap impl. I suppose you are right in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`final` and `private` say nothing about the [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) (or lack thereof) of the *object* named by said variable. (They modify the *variable*, not the *object*.) Anyway ..

---

The *variable* will be consistent across threads if it is a [final field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's `final` fields.

The actual [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) *object* is "thread safe" insofar as the guarantees it makes. In particular, only *single* method calls/operations are guaranteed and as such using larger synchronization code may be required .. which is easily controlled if the CHM is only accessible from the object that created it.

Using `private` is normally considered good because it *prevents* other code from "accidently" accessing a variable (and thus the object it names) when they should not. However, the private modifier does *not* establish the same happens-before guarantee as the `final` modifier and is thus orthogonal to thread-safety.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point. To sum up - it's possibly to gurantee consistency of CHM object without `final` keyword, but it's easier just to write `final` and forgot about implementation tricks which intended to gurantee not-null consistence reference.

Comment: @Baurzhan Consistency of the *variable* (CHM's own construction/code adds guarantees for the CHM *object* itself, perhaps with `final` fields of its own). Unlike `synchronized` happens-before guarantees, this guarantee of `final` fields is limited immediately to the variable itself.